# When parsing a dict of a dict, is there a wild card option I can use to access nested dict?

Tags: python

I have this data:

```
 {'6': {'Change': '109,438',
  'Name': 'Prologis Inc',
  'Owned': '609,826',
  'Weight': ' 2.14'},
 '7': {'Change': '48,032',
  'Name': 'The Home Depot Inc',
  'Owned': '208,967',
  'Weight': ' 2.02'},
 '8': {'Change': '61,235',
  'Name': 'Facebook Inc A',
  'Owned': '220,558',
  'Weight': ' 2.01'},
 '9': {'Change': '32,045',
  'Name': 'NextEra Energy Inc',
  'Owned': '205,412',
  'Weight': ' 1.98'}}
```

it's a dict within a dict and I want to extract 'Name' & 'Weight'. I'm struggling to get past the first layer(the one with the numbers) so this code isn't working:

```
mylist = []
stocks = holdings[0]
for s in stocks:
    m = (s['Name'], s['Weight'])
    mylist.append(m)
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to accomplish, but I would load the data into a pandas DataFrame for easy analysis and graphing. `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stocks, orient='index')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to iterate over `stocks.values()` to get the values rather than the keys:

```
>>> [(s['Name'], s['Weight']) for s in stocks.values()]
[('Prologis Inc', ' 2.14'), ('The Home Depot Inc', ' 2.02'), ('Facebook Inc A', ' 2.01'), ('NextEra Energy Inc', ' 1.98')]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you're iterating over the dictionary's keys (in this case numbers).
To iterate over key-value pairs you should use stocks.items():

```
for i, stock in stocks.items():
    m = (stock['Name'], stock['Weight'])
```

Answer (score 1):

In the given data, the `weight` is in string format. I think you need to parse the weight in float.

```
import json

data = {'6': {'Change': '109,438',
  'Name': 'Prologis Inc',
  'Owned': '609,826',
  'Weight': ' 2.14'},
 '7': {'Change': '48,032',
  'Name': 'The Home Depot Inc',
  'Owned': '208,967',
  'Weight': ' 2.02'},
 '8': {'Change': '61,235',
  'Name': 'Facebook Inc A',
  'Owned': '220,558',
  'Weight': ' 2.01'},
 '9': {'Change': '32,045',
  'Name': 'NextEra Energy Inc',
  'Owned': '205,412',
  'Weight': ' 1.98'}}


pairs = []
for stock in data.values():
    pairs.append((stock['Name'], float(stock['Weight'].strip())))
print(json.dumps(pairs, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    [
        "Prologis Inc",
        2.14
    ],
    [
        "The Home Depot Inc",
        2.02
    ],
    [
        "Facebook Inc A",
        2.01
    ],
    [
        "NextEra Energy Inc",
        1.98
    ]
]
```